# What are good standard administrative privileges for review site?

Tags: web, admin, privileges, administrator

I am building a review website from scratch and I am curious whether there are any good guidelines on administrative privileges?  The reason being, I don't want the site to go live and have missed some important privilege that an administrator should have over standard users (and maybe moderators as well).  I will do testing as well but I'd like to start on the right foot...

This specific site will have two types of users; businesses and customers.  Each account will have profile information (name, address, hours, etc) and businesses will be able to upload multimedia (pictures and videos etc).  Customers can also leave reviews for businesses, which also include multimedia.

What is best practice?  Should I give administrator full privileges or is that asking for trouble?

**EDIT**

At least, which things should administrators never have access to.  For example, obviously they shouldn't be able to edit the UID or primary key.

Comment: So far, I was thinking the administrator can delete accounts, edit business account information, delete multimedia, and delete reviews.

Comment: you're fishing for opinions. we have no idea what your requirements/needs are.

Comment: True, but aren't best practices, like say for AngularJS development or even just straight HTML, opinionated anyways?  It helps to follow them, which is why I am asking.  I have edited the question to help people find a scope for the answer.